# Trouble Understanding toggleClass

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Hi there so i went on the Jquery api documentation website for this function and still don't understand how it works.  Did some extended research and still don't understand it.

So im gonna give an example and just would like somebody to walk through what I'm doing wrong and what is the right thing to do.

For Example Lets say i would like to animate a pink square

```
<body>

<div id=square>

</div>

</body>
<style>
#square {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: pink;
border: 1px solid aqua;
}

.square {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: pink;
border: 1px solid aqua;
}


</style>


<script>
$("#square").click(function(){
$(this).animate({width: "500px",
height: "500px"
});

/* which makes this pink square animate to  500px X 500px
and then once its rechecked i put the toggle class to have it toggle        class back to .square which is the original position, But it seems not to    be working.*/

 $("#square").click(function(){
$("#square").toggleClass(".square");
});
});


</script>
```

Comment: Well, your `#square` and `.square` are the exact same...

Comment: WELL CAN YOU TOGGLE AN ID , I THOUGH YOU CAN ONLY TOGGLE A CLASS

Comment: There is no property that would change during the animation.

Comment: so you cannot reverse a animation

Comment: I didn't say that.  I said that there is no difference between the different styles you're using.

Comment: It is a typo `toggleClass("square")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your html is, but assuming that the #square and .square are both the same element your css will favor your id styles over the class styles, so even if the class is toggling you won't see any change if the id also has styles for it.

Also, for the .toggleClass() call you don't need to place the period before the class. Same for addClass(), removeClass, etc.

Here I gave the element your background color and then gave the class the new color (classes will override elements in css just like IDs will override classes).

**html**

```
<div id="square" class="square"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: pink;
}
#square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid aqua;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#square").click(function(){
    $("#square").toggleClass("square");
});
```

Also, in case it helps, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/t4065exj/).

Comment: hey thanks dude very good explanation, A couple questions can you toggle a id, or only classes

Comment: With jQuery you're limited to toggleClass() I believe, but for IDs you could create a conditional statement for adding and removing attributes... IDs and class are both attributes. In most cases I'd recommended sticking to toggling a class though since there is supposed to be only one of a single ID on each page and each element is supposed to be limited to a single ID.